# Unable to boot Ubuntu with new Kernel but it works fine with old kernel

Tags: 12.04, grub2, kernel

I recently acquired a Samsung Series 9-900x3c and installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it.

Now I wanted to upgrade to the most recent kernel and after grabbing the packages from "kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/" and installing them via dpkg Ubuntu fails to boot. I can select the appropriate Kernel version in grub but when I try to launch the Ubuntu with kernel 3.6 nothing happens.

On the other hand Kernel 3.2.x works fine for me.

Any suggestions what I can do to use the most recent Kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your kernel installation. anwyay to correct that problem boot from your kernel 3.2.x which is working just fine. and follow the following steps which leads you to compile a new kernel and thus obtain a 2 deb files (image and header). just please follow this [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I switched to Kernel 3.5 and it seems to work without problems now.